# Django problem, code cannot find css and js static files. Somehow I haven't django nginx conf

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu, static

my problem is

```
[18/Dec/2020 12:56:24] "GET /login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6096
[18/Dec/2020 12:56:24] "GET /static/grappelli/stylesheets/screen.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[18/Dec/2020 12:56:24] "GET /static/grappelli/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[18/Dec/2020 12:56:24] "GET /static/grappelli/stylesheets/mueller/grid/output.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[18/Dec/2020 12:56:24] "GET /static/grappelli/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[18/Dec/2020 12:56:24] "GET /static/grappelli/jquery/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[18/Dec/2020 12:56:24] "GET /static/grappelli/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[18/Dec/2020 12:56:24] "GET /static/grappelli/js/grappelli.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

But with `DEBUG = True` everything works well. But I want to work without Debug. I saw a similar problem here(stackoverflow) where `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` conflicted with nginx django, but I couldn't find any django config anywhere in `/etc/nginx/`. I installed nginx after django, I think this might be a problem. What to do now, how to fix it? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Django's dev-server will handle static files only with `DEBUG=True`.
Explanation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Use `./manage runserver` only while developing because the dev-server is pretty slow.

You should manually setup Nginx to work with your Django app.

1. Install and setup Gunicorn or uWSGI (I'd prefer Gunicorn because it is simplier to use). This is the server which will run your app.
2. Setup Nginx to work with Gunicorn/uWSGI.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/